# AWS Lambda Function has no logs in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have two Lambda function, both scheduled by the same Rule. The older one is working fine, and I'm trying to determine if the newer one is running.  I think it is based on the graphs on the monitoring page.

But for the newer one, under "Recent Invocations" on the monitoring page, it says "No Data Found".  It is scheduled to run every minute during working hours.

When I click the link "View Logs in Cloudwatch" in the upper right of the monitoring page, it says:

```
Log group does not exist
The specific log group: /aws/lambda/MyFunctionName does not exist in this account or region.
```

Is there someway to turn this on?  I thought logging was always on.

I also ran the function manually with the "Test" button, and it didn't create a log either.

Screen shots:

1. IAM Policy (after adding CloudWatchFull)
   [image]
   Again, the one that logs and the one that doesn't log use the same role.
   After adding CloudWatchFull, still no log.
2. On the "monitoring" tab of Lambda Function:
   [image]
3. After clicking "View Logs in Cloudwatch Link"
   [image]

Comment: By default logging will be enabled, Check if your IAM role has permissions to add the cloud watch log group. Also if you run the function manually using Test button, the ouput console will have hyper link to log group

Comment: Could you post the policies attached to the role that the new lambda is using?

Comment: I can post policies later, but I did mention that both Lambda functions run under same IAM role.

Comment: Added screenshots to question.

Comment: In theory, it simply needs the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy. Your policy seems like it has extra characters after the name, suggesting that it is a custom policy rather than the one supplied by AWS. This was possibly auto-created for a different Lambda function. Please change it to use the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` that is marked as **AWS managed**. No other permissions are required to enable logging.